# Circular Include with class members

Tags: c++, reference, circular-dependency

I have a problem with circular include and forward declaration:

I have the following classes:

A.h

```
class B;

class A{
private:
    B b;
}
```

A.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

A():b(){

}
```

B.h

```
class A;

class B{

    private:
        const A& a;
        B();
        loadA(const A& a_);

}
```

B.cpp

```
 #include "B.h"

 B(){
 }

 loadA(const A& a_){
    a = a_;
 }
```

The compiler says that in "A.h" the type B is incomplete. Is there a way to implement A and B relation , compiling, without using Pointers?

Thank you

Comment: Sure,  Just include b.h in a.h and get rid of the forward declaration of `B` in a.h.

Comment: `B(){}` should give you an error since it fails to initialize a reference member.

Comment: Thank you very much NathanOliver and aschepler both right suggestions, I followed both and it's working!